# Importing excel table to ASP.NET C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have table in a excel sheet called ListProduct.xls. When I import the excel file I want it to print the table in success page. The index page works fine I can click on browse and lets me pick the excel file. But when I click import it gives me an error on my Product controller.

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/" + excelfile.FileName);
```

It gives me an error in this line. The error it shows is

> NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code. An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

ProductController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.IO;
using ImportExcelFileInASPNETMVC.Models;

namespace ImportExcelFileInASPNETMVC.Controllers
{
public class ProductController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Import(HttpPostedFileBase excelfile)
    {
        if (excelfile == null || excelfile.ContentLength == 0)
        {
            ViewBag.Error = "Please select a excel file<br>";
            return View("Index");
        }
        else
        {
            if (excelfile.FileName.EndsWith("xls") || excelfile.FileName.EndsWith("xlsx"))
            {
                string path = Server.MapPath("~/Content/" + excelfile.FileName);
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
                    System.IO.File.Delete(path);
                excelfile.SaveAs(path);
                // Read data from excel file
                Excel.Application application = new Excel.Application();
                Excel.Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(path);
                Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
                Excel.Range range = worksheet.UsedRange;
                List<Product> listProducts = new List<Product>();
                for (int row = 3; row <= range.Rows.Count; row++)
                {
                    Product p = new Product();
                    p.Name = ((Excel.Range)range.Cells[row, 2]).Text;
                    listProducts.Add(p);
                }
                ViewBag.ListProducts = listProducts;
                return View("Success");
            }
            else
         {
            ViewBag.Error = "File type is incorrect<br>";
            return View("Index");
         }

    }
   }
  }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@{
Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Import", "Product", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype  = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Error)
    <span>Excel File </span><input type="file" name="excelfile" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Import" />
}
</body>
</html>
```

Success.cshtml

```
@{
Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Success</title>
</head>
<body>
<table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var p in ViewBag.ListProducts)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@p.Name</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to step back and separate these tasks into individual functions. Maybe a function to handle the upload, a function to handle the excel parsing, and then something to handle the loading the parsed data into the form for display. Secondly, using Excel Interop is going to cause all kinds of headaches in troubleshooting and that's probably where the NotSupportedException is coming from. I would switch to a library like ClosedXMl or EPPuls to parse the Excel file.

Comment: I'm new to programming and just trying to learn i got this code from the website. I'm not sure how to use ClosedXMI or EPPuls. If you could take some of your valuable time and write or edit how the code is supposed to look like that would be great

Answer (score 0):

its a problem probably because of `HttpPostedFileBase`. Try this, post the file by keeping input[type='file'] in your @Html.BeginForm. And on server access the file using this,

```
var firstFile=Request.Files[0];
```

In addition you need to check on client as well as on server the type of file to allow (in your case it should be excel file)

Comment: Other types of excel files?

Comment: with other types he means, .xls .xlsx etc.